# print value of a node, print_node(const Node * n), in a Binary search tree

Tags: c++, algorithm, nodes, binary-search-tree

I understand the idea of recursion, just not the implementation. I don't understand how you pass in a node that isn't root. I have a header file and a ccp. The node class is a private subclass of a BST class. So I'm guessing it's to be called from within the BST class. But how do I traverse the tree and match nodes? 
Are nodes comparable (Node n == root->left)?
Would it be better to compare values, (n->value == root->left->value)? and then if they're equal print out the value?
since I also can't change the node, how do I recursively call this? Should I go the route of an helper function that takes in two nodes? the const Node* n and a Node* t, let's say

```
class BST {
class Node { // binary tree node
public:
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
    Value value;
    int level;
    Node(const Value v = Value(), int lev = 1)
        : value(v), level(lev), left(nil), right(nil)
    {}
    Value& content() { return value; }

}; // Node

Node* root;
```

public:
    void print_node(const Node* n) {//Print the node's value.

```
}

Value print_node(const Node *n, Node *t){

}
```

Comment: Show the code, please.  Don't just describe it.

Comment: Why do you want to use a recursion to traverse the tree? It is more inefficient and not recommended for extensive depth of the recursion.

Comment: What are you trying to do: print the entire tree, print a specific node, or find a node and then print it?

Comment: @BajMile Recursion is a natural way to traverse trees. The depth of a balanced BST is log2(number of nodes), which isn't much - a tree of depth 32 literally contains billions of nodes.

Comment: @molbdnilo -what is the algorithms book which you are reading? traverse can be done very easily without recursion, recursion is slower and dangerous for big trees (can lead to stack-overflow for example)

Answer (score 0):

Can't do much without the code, or a better description, so I'm going to explain the issue you seem to be having around 'root' vs 'node'.

First off, 'root' is a type of node.  Code-wise, it shouldn't actually look any different than other node objects and should be set up via `Node* root = new Node();`  'Root' is just a name that we give a special type of node that has no parent nodes, and does not warrant a completely new data structure.  If I were to use a separate example using a `Person` class with the field `gender`, you could describe any `Person* person = new Person();` object as being 'female' simply because the field 
`gender == female"`, without having to create a completely new class called `Female`.

With that out of the way, since recursion implementations of trees don't often look at parents, passing a 'root' should be the exact same as passing a regular node.  If you defined the following method in rough pseudocode:

```
define BSTVisit(Node* node, Node* nodeToFind) {
    switch (compareNodes(node, nodeToFind)) {
        case MATCH:
            print(node->name);
            break;
        case LESS_THAN:
            BSTVisit(node->leftChild, nodeToFind);
            break;
        case MORE_THAN:
            BSTVisit(node->rightChild, nodeToFind);
            break;
    }
}
```

You would initiate the code by calling `BSTVisit(root, nodeToFind)`.  From there it would treat 'root' as a regular node, access its children as necessary, and continue until it's done.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how the tree traverse can be non-recursive, we are starting from the root and check the key value at each node. if recursion depth is too big it can cause stack overflow ( even if this is not very probable for binary trees traverse) and the recursive traverse is slower than the non-recursive.

```
template <class T>
Node* BinTree<T>::findParent(const T& key, bool& bExist) const
{
    Node* parent = root;
    bExist = false ;
    while(root)
    {
        parent = root ;
        if ( key < root->key )
            root = root->left ;
        else if ( key > root->key )
            root = root->right ;    
        else
        {
            bExist = true ;
            return root ;
        }
    }

    return parent;
}
```